# FFServer over https

Tags: video, https, ffserver

we're currently providing video/audo feeds via ffserver over "http" i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/folder/feed1.mjpg`

however, now we need to add the feeds to secure pages over "https" so we need to do something like this `https://127.0.0.1:8000/folder/feed1.mjpg`

I have searched the web and docs, but didn't find anything in reference to ffserver and https.
Is this possible? if so can anyone point me in the direction of achieving this?

Comment: There are no direct options in [`ffserver`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ffserver) to spit out the stream on a secure channel. So Lucky G.'s answer is certainly the best you can do, although you could use Nginx instead of Apache2.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - embedding the ffserver's non-encrypted WEBM stream into HTTPS web site was causing the browser's "mixed content" warning.
I solved the problem by using Apache with mod_proxy.
I basically followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

In short, I made only these 3 steps:

1. enable the proxy modules

   ```
   a2enmod proxy
   a2enmod proxy_http
   ```
2. create a new virtual host in Apache listening on port 443 with the following directives:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName livestream.example.com
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8090/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8090/

     SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
     Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. set up DNS record for `livestream.example.com`

My ffserver is running on the same server as Apache, with HTTP port 8090, but I'm sure the proxy can be directed to any other IP address.

That way I was able to embed the WEBM video stream as https://livestream.example.com/somevideo.webm and get rid of the mixed content warning.

(tested on Ubuntu 16.04, Apache 2.4.18, ffserver 2.8.11)

Comment: As a side note, if you use port 443 for your website, you may want to use a different port for the camera. Also, the `ProxyPass[Reserve]` should probably use `127.0.0.1` if the `ffserver` is on the same machine.